# AngularJS 2.0 - post data to Laravel method

Tags: laravel, angular

Let's say I built an API with Laravel that allows to index and store **heroes** in my database.

This is how my store method looks like in my laravel hero controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $hero = new Hero;
        $hero->name = $request->name;
        $hero->description = $request->description;
        $hero->avatar = "None";
        $hero->save();

        $heroes = Hero::paginate(5);
        return view('/heroes/index', [
        'heroes' => $heroes
    ]);
    }
```

The method above sends the request data to the right field in my database.

**My question is:** how I can manipulate and send form data to this method and fetch the returned result using Angular 2.0?

In other words: how I can use Angular 2.0 to work with my laravel API?

This is my angular2.0 method used to show the list of heroes:

```
getHeroes() {
      this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.heroes = data;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done');
      );
  }
```

so.. how do I create one from my angular?

```
    addHero() {

      let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let formPayload = new URLSearchParams();
    formPayload.set('name', name);
    formPayload.set('description', description);

       this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/heroes', formPayload.toString(), { headers: headers })
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
        data => { this.heroes = data;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done');
      );
  }
```

Error: `failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

My angular form:

```
<form method="post">
    Hero name: <input type="text" name="name" [ngModel]="name"><br/>
    Hero description: <input type="text" name="description" [ngModel]="description">
    <button (click)="addHero()" class="btn btn-primary">Add this hero!</button>
    </form>
```

My laravel working form:

```
<!-- New Hero Form -->
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/heroes" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="knUS8vUxihTj4YJhjVkqmRBJJkVDDCABIZaRwXhN">

            <!-- Hero Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hero-name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Hero Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="hero-name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Hero Description -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hero-description" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Hero Description</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" name="description" id="hero-description" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Add Hero Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Hero
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First to send data to laravel in angular you need to change your request from get to post.

```
getHeroes() {
  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes')
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => { this.heroes = data;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done');
  );
```

}

At the laravel store function you need to send a json response since you are consuming the api in a json format.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $hero = new Hero;
    $hero->name = $request->name;
    $hero->description = $request->description;
    $hero->avatar = "None";
    $hero->save();

    $heroes = Hero::paginate(5)->toArray();
    return response()->json($heroes);
]);
}
```

Comment: AngularJS gets `500 (Internal Server Error)`, I think becuase no data is sent to my laravel api. How I can send my form data to the api? There is no mention to any form input data in your answer. This is my form: `<form method="post">
 Hero name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
 Hero description: <input type="text" name="description">
 <button (click)="addHero()" class="btn btn-primary">Add this hero!</button>
 </form>`. The AddHero() method is pretty same to your comment's code.

Comment: Check if your route path is correct. Do you have this in your route file "**/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes**" ?

Comment: I changed this to the right URL, and yes, I do have it in my route file. if I haven't, I think it would return 404.

Answer (score 0):

To send a request with a JSON payload:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var obj = {
  name: this.name,
  description: this.description,
  '_token': this.token
};

 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes', JSON.stringify(obj), { headers: headers })
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.heroes = data;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done');
  );
```

Don't forget to import the Headers class along with Http one:

```
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
```

**Edit**

If you want to send a form, use the following:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let formPayload = new URLSearchParams();
formPayload.set('name', this.name);
formPayload.set('description', this.description);
formPayload.set('_token', this.token);
 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes', formPayload.toString(), { headers: headers })
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe( ... );
```

and the corresponding form:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" [ngModel]="token"
         value="knUS8vUxihTj4YJhjVkqmRBJJkVDDCABIZaRwXhN">
  Hero name: <input type="text" name="name" [ngModel]="name"><br/>
  Hero description: <input type="text" name="description" [ngModel]="description">
  <button (click)="addHero()" class="btn btn-primary">Add this hero!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: AngularJS gets `500 (Internal Server Error)`, I think becuase no data is sent to my laravel api. How I can send my form data to the api? There is no mention to any form input data in your answer. This is my form: `<form method="post">
 Hero name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
 Hero description: <input type="text" name="description">
 <button (click)="addHero()" class="btn btn-primary">Add this hero!</button>
 </form>`. The AddHero() method is pretty same to your comment's code.

Comment: I updated my answer with the way to post à form in angular2. Feel free to tell if that corresponds to your need.

Comment: What do I replace the 'some name' in order to get my form input named "name"?

Comment: You could set an ngModel attribute on your input: <input [ngModel]="someField"/>. Then you can use the someField property: formPayload.set('name', someField);

Comment: Now I get `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: formPayload is not defined`. updated my addHero() method on my main post.

Comment: Do you import the class URLSearchParams Alinghi with the Http one?

Comment: There was also a typo. It's rather `let formPayload = new URLSearchParams();` instead of `URLSearchParams formPayload = new URLSearchParams();`. I updated my answer...

Comment: Updated my app, but now another error appears. `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: description is not defined`. Updated my question with my actual form and updated method..

Comment: You need to use `this.name` and `this.description` since they are properties of your component class...

Comment: What a shame, sorry about that. anywayw, error 500 still appears http://i.imgur.com/uFThPVm.png

Comment: No worries ;-) Which version do you use. I know that there are some problems with zones in beta10 and beta11... You could try a version before or beta12.

Comment: The zone is not the problem here. the problem is the "failed to load" error, status code 500 when using http.post to laravel..

Comment: Oh sorry! Why do your request fails on the server side? How does the server expect for data structure (json, form in payload, query parameters)?

Comment: I updated my question with my laravel working form template. I'm just trying to make it with Angular. seem like the token is missing?

Comment: Yes you have an hidden input for a token... You also need to bind it with `ngModel`...

Comment: Still error 500. I put this linese now in my angular method: `console.log("NAME IS: " + this.name);
   console.log("Description: " + this.description);` and both are undefined